# Toggle Class Firing but No Changes Taking Place

Tags: jquery, css

I know there are multiple threads on this topic, but none of them provide a fix for my issue.

I'm trying to implement a toggleClass feature - when a logo is clicked, the page goes dark and displays some text.  Click the logo again and the page is restored to the original style.

I can see the event firing in the developer console, but no changes are taking place.  I've tried using addClass & removeClass in place of toggle, and I've tried messing with the z index of the visible element, no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a link to the site.  The logo is in the top left corner.

[Inline Link](http://www.justincefai.co/)

```
<a class="nav-link"><%= image_tag "jclogo.png", alt: "logo", class: "jclogo", id: "jclogo"%></a>

<div id="logo-bg" class="logo-bg">yo.</div>
```

```
.jclogo {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.logo-bg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.logo-bg .visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 9000;
}
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("jclogo");

    function cover() {
      $(".logo-bg").toggleClass("visible");
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", cover);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're toggling a class on `.logo-bg`, so you need to chain the class names with no space between them.

Change this:

```
.logo-bg .visible {
  …
}
```

Into this:

```css
.logo-bg.visible {
  …
}
```

### Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("jclogo");

  function cover() {
    $(".logo-bg").toggleClass("visible");
  }
  button.addEventListener("click", cover);
});
```

```css
.logo-bg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.logo-bg.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 9000;
}

body {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

#jclogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="jclogo">button</button>
<div class="logo-bg"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnv1eLkd/)

Comment: Man, it works perfect in the jsFiddle, but no dice on my site.  I went ahead and pushed the change live so you can check it out if you want.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JustinCefai You should make your `<a>` into an action `<button>`, move the `id` on the `<img>` to the `<button>`, and set the click event listener on the `<button>`.

Comment: @JustinCefai Try setting up something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/pb0nc6xe/).

Comment: Thanks Andy!  After some tinkering I was able to get the behavior working, but only with the addClass method, and for some reason it ignores the navbar and that stays white.  I found some SO links on those so I'm going to keep messing with it.  I appreciate your help!